# BorderWidth issue in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a listview filled with cards, when i set `borderWidth`(`borderLeftWidth,borderBottomWidth` like that) some cards does display it, and some cards doesn't, what could be the issue ?

I tried

> 1. to increase the `borderWidth` value then i can see the border but in different width
> 2. when i change the component's height(decrease or incresase), this issue is not coming anymore,

I cannot figure out the relation.

Comment: Are the ones that aren't rendering start their initial render off screen? For a example, the bottom item is crossing the bottom of the view and when you scroll it you can the messed up border?

Comment: i read something in PixelRatio documentation under pixel grid snapping,  how to do the  thing right ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html